# Binding action to a nested CheckBox using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a MainView.xaml containing a ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="Conditions"/>
```

The backing model MainViewModel.cs contains the ObservableCollection used to populate the List:

```
private ObservableCollection<ConditionViewModel> _conditions = new ObservableCollection<ConditionViewModel>();
public ObservableCollection<ConditionViewModel> Conditions
{
    get { return _conditions; }
    set
    {
        _conditions= value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Conditions);
    }
}

//QUESTION: How do I call this function when a checkbox inside the ListView is checked/unchecked?
public void ConditionStateChanged(ICondition condition)
{

}
```

The ConditionView.xaml that renders each item in the list is just a checkbox with some text:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="IsSelected"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Description"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The ConditionViewModel.cs backing each item in the list looks like the following:

```
public class ConditionViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsSelected);
        }
    }

    private readonly ICondition _condition;

    public ConditionViewModel(ICondition condition)
    {
        _condition = condition;
    }
}
```

Here's my question.  Whenever an item is checked or unchecked inside the ListView, I need to perform some action inside MainViewModel.cs that contains the ListView.  You can see the function I want to call above, it's named ConditionStateChanged().  How can I do this the 'right' (Caliburn.Micro) way.

Currently, all I can think of, is posting a C# event from inside of IsSelected property inside ConditionViewModel, and then subscribing to that event inside the parent MainViewModel.  From the event 'sender' parameter, I would know which ICondition object triggered it, and I could call my intended: ConditionStateChanged() function.  Is that the right approach?  Thanks.

Comment: You are already posting an event `PropertyChanged` just subscribe to that event and listed for the `IsSelected` property by name. then do what you wanted

Comment: @Nkosi Indeed.  A much simpler solution to my event idea.  Thanks.  Is it the best way of going about what I try to do?  There's no way I can bind in XAML using Caliburn instead?